# Shopify Facebook store javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, image, resize, shopify

I'm new to using Shopify, and our company is creating a facebook store for our product.

Our product requires the user to upload an image with every unit bought (they are customized). Does anyone know how we can include a file input in the checkout form? Or even in the thank you screen?

Also, we would like to have an image resize tool included, which we have a javascript package for. Is there a way to modify HTML and include javascript through Shopify's facebook store? I know it is possible through themes in regular shopify, but we can't seem to find the equivalent in the facebook version of shopify.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't add html or JavaScript on the checkout [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/?ref=microapps) checkout.
Why don't you ask the user to upload the image on the same product page, just before sending the user to ../cart?